# How would military branches for other planets be organized when earth is still the most relevant battlefield?

Tags: warfare, future, military-organisation

How would military branches for other planets be organized when earth is still the most relevant battlefield? While it easy to find examples of fiction where humanity hasn't left the solar & planets have their own governments. There aren't many examples of fiction where while conflict occurs off of earth often, but most conflict is still between earth nations & off world colonies still tend to be tied to earth. This makes it difficult to find examples of established off world militaries where the off world military is secondary. So how would branches for militaries with a focus on earth but still have to operate on other planets work. Would off world forces get their own branches or would they be part of regular forces? If so would how would the branches containing the space navy & off-world ground forces be organized?

Notes:
In this world no one has left the solar system. Shipping from earth is expensive so only things that are difficult to make & light are shipped up. With most of the the manufacturing capacity for heavier things that are needed in space is centralised on the moon & a few large stations in high earth orbit around earth. Off world militarization has been around for a while & is established. Most militaries still roughly follow the army, navy, air force structure (+ expeditionary branch (marines or airborne) for larger militaries) for on earth combat.

if your read any part of this description **Off world warfare is not the primary from of warfare in this world, most combat still takes place on earth, off-earth warfare *is* secondary to on earth warfare.**

edit: i don't know why i have gotten down downvoted, i though i was pretty implicit I my question that i am *Not* talking about generic structures for sci-fi militaries.

My question is about how nations would structure the branches they would integrate the forces they use for "space navies" & forces intended for fighting on other planets *in the solar system* into their existing structure of their army, navy & airforce that are still primarily dedicated to warfare on earth.

Comment: What else they can bring than terroristic actions and guerilla tactics at best - so lookup those. Also tactics is inseparable from the weapon and equipment, all u wrote does not matter that much. What weapon do they use, how many is there of them - those things will define what they can or can not do and how they do what they can. Idk downvoted the q for this and other reasons.

Comment: VTC:OB. Earth's militaries are not standardized. How can we then know how they would be organized off-world? What makes you think that existing structure wouldn't be used? How will you judge a best answer? Please remember that raw fishing-for-ideas questions don't work well on Stack Exchange, where the model is one-specific-question/one-best answer and the Q is expected to be objective. Open-ended Qs and Qs where every answer is equally valid are specifically off-topic (see [help/dont-ask]). (And you've likely been DV because you're asking about window dressing, not a rule of your world.)

Answer (score 1):

Within the United States, there are three major branches of the military. The Army, Navy, and Air Force. Now, we're all a little too young to be aware that the Air Force is a recent addition having only been created as its own branch in 1947... before this it was part of the Army (Army Air Corps).

Some political maneuvering during the aftermath of WWII is responsible for its existence as an autonomous branch of the military. During this time frame you had Air Corps generals arguing that this was necessary to expertly handle the various new weapon systems that had been developed. Nuclear weapons, ICBMs and other missiles, supersonic bombers, etc.

So, at least within the US military microculture, it would probably require similar circumstances for that to happen again, and it wouldn't happen often. Expect few or no new branches.

Instead, the US military would organize these new planets (and deep space) as theaters of operation, and label those "commands". You'd have a USMARSCOM and a USMOONCOM and so forth just as you now have a USPACOM (Pacific Command). Within these "commands", there'd be liaison officers who would coordinate action among the branches of the military.

However, the US is not the only military on Earth. And in your story, it may not even exist as an independent entity. Other major militaries on Earth organize differently. In some cases vastly so.

Thus, depending on how nations are organize on Earth, just about anything is possible. These things are rather arbitrary. Instead, focus on developing chain-of-command structures, where each unit and each soldier knows whom they answer to such that the story still seems plausibly military-ish. Base your soldiers off of extant marine cultures, since marines are the expeditionary forces of any given country (those ones that are shipped across an ocean to land and go fight somewhere). Base those who stay on ships and use its guns on sailors. The naming/labeling of these can be quite creative and if you get the basics right can't detract from the story.

Answer (score 0):

### You'd have a local militia and earthbound units.

The goal for earth will be to control colonies as cheaply as possible, and make them produce lots of extremely valuable materials they can sell back to earth. As such, they'll want to have a small number of elite troops, and a much larger number of local colonists with lighter weapons.

The earth military forces will have origins that depends on who funds them. Some will be from countries, and so they'll have military designations like the countries. Some will be mercenaries hired by companies to protect their investments, and so they'll have a corporate handler and whatever ranks the company has. Some will be multinational groups with multiple countries of soldiers with different organizational structures.

They'll probably have [a space force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Space_Force) for many militaries, a separate branch with expertise in flying space ships to help people get around, who will transport whatever soldiers are necessary to colonies.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of **branch** structure, my question refers to military branches work rather than overall structure

Comment: @OT-64SKOT without providing information on population sizes and technology only very general answers can be given.  For example, a hollowed-out asteroid with a population of 1000 people probably has 10 or so people who have a broad mandate covering law enforcement, customs, biosecurity, immigration and what passes for defence.  A densely populated moon with 25 million people will have a much larger force with much more specialisation.  Development and social acceptance of autonomous systems will shape structure enormously.  Provide more detail in the question and answers can be more detailed.

Comment: My question is already defined. My question is about how nations would structure the branches of their militaries dedicated to protecting there space colonies, while they still have a heavier focus on forces for fighting other nations on earth.

Comment: I answered the question- they'd follow the existing command structures of normal military units. You can google each individual nation to see how they structure army units. 

Nations like the USA already have a military branch devoted to space travel, so no changes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no single answer for everybody.**

Branches and specialties and corps and rank structures and equipment and training are all subordinate to three factors:

- The current threat environment
- The culture of the society
- The resources available

You can organize forces in your Solar System any way you wish, as long as it makes sense to those three factors.

Historically, colonial local reserve forces (also called 'militia' in some places and times) tended to focus on defensive missions. Their strategic job was to deter attack by making the cost of an attack too high for an enemy to bother. Their operational task was to deny the colony to the enemy until decisive additional forces arrived.

They were sometimes structured similarly to Regular forces, sometimes not. Sometimes their leadership was integrated with Regular forces, sometimes not. Sometimes their training was good, sometimes poor. Sometimes they had modern equipment, sometimes ancient.

Ultimately, in many conflicts, the structure that many forces used is whatever they thought had the best likelihood of winning. Roosevelt and Eisenhower didn't care which "service" operated their amphibious landing craft or antisubmarine aircraft or bomber defenses.

Comment: I am not talking about general structure i am talking about *branch* structure. Which there as far i know of most nations use a simple army, navy & airforce structure for earth warfare, with maybe something like an independent marine corps thrown in for bigger militaries & getting rid of the navy if your landlocked. With strategic considerations changing this very little between countries. While the internal structure for these services vary depending on strategic forces.  The basic army navy & airforce structure does not. My question is about how the forces used for warfare in space would be

Comment: (cont.) integrated into that existing structure

Comment: They can be structured *any way that works*, including Branch structure. Canada got rid of separate Branches entirely, and is an effective land/sea/air force. In Iraq, I was in a single USA unit with folks from three Branches (and two more from different countries) because that's what the mission required. There are historical reasons for separate Branches (usually related to procurement, training, and career progression). Those matter only if the culture of your fictional countries wants them to matter.

Comment: > Canada got rid of separate Branches entirely, and is an effective land/sea/air force. 
they still effectively have branches, you can't do things like exchange officer between the branches on a regular basis because a navy captain isn't interchangeable with an army colonel. They even brought back separate rank titles for the branches after a bit

Comment: (cont.) >was in a single USA unit with folks from three Branches (and two more from different countries) because that's what the mission required.
Yes but that was still separate branches working together. If you unified branches entirely you would get issues like whatever part of the military the guy doing procurement was from would most likely kill any procurement projects for other areas of the military to get more budget for the projects from their area of the military

Comment: Seems pretty clear that this isn't the kind of answer you wanted. You must be prepared for that when you toss an open question into Worldbuilding. There are people here experienced in many different backgrounds, and the answers will reflect that.